# Minimum value of a for which $f(x)=x^2 + ax +1$ is strictly increasing in$ [1,2]$.

Tags: functions, derivatives

$f(x)=x^2 + ax +1$

$f'(x)=2x+a$

Given interval is $[1,2]$

$\Rightarrow 1\le x\le 2$

$\Rightarrow 2\le 2x\le 4$

$\Rightarrow (2+a)\le(2x+a)\le(4+a)$

$\Rightarrow (2+a)\le f'(x)\le (4+a)$

For $f$ to be strictly increasing in $(1,2)$ $f'(x) >0$ for all $x \in (1,2)$

$\Rightarrow 2x+a>0$

$\Rightarrow x>\frac{-a}{2}$

Here, I notice that $a$ can taken on infinitely large values to satisfy the inequality. For least value of $a$; $0, -1,-2,-3$ holds good, but $-4$ doesn't.

I'm not sure what to do next.

**Edit:** In the newer version of the textbook which I just downloaded, the interval has been changed from $(1,2)$ to $[1,2]$ and so I've edited the question as such.

Answer (score 1):

You have correctly observed that  $$f'(x) > 0 \,,\, x \in [1,2] $$ $$\implies 2x + a >0 \,, \, x \in [1,2]$$

For $x=1$, we get: $$2+ a >0 \implies a >-2 \tag 1$$

For $x =2$, we get: $$4+ a >0 \implies a >-4 \tag 2$$

Hence, we have the least value of $a $ as: $\,? $

Comment: $4+a>0 \Rightarrow a>-4 \Rightarrow a=-3.999999...$  is the minimum value of $a$?

Comment: Wanted to inform you that I have edited the interval in the question.

Comment: @mettledmike Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You've got: $f^\prime(x) > 2+a$.

You want: $f^\prime(x) > 0$.

You can get what you want if $2+a \geq 0$.

Hence, you want $2+a\geq 0$, that is, $a\geq -2$.

Comment: It would help to clarify that $f'(x) \ge f'(1) = 2 + a$

Answer (score 0):

Saying that $f^\prime(x)=2x+a \ge 2 +a$ is positive on $(1,2)$ is equivalent to say that $a+2 >0$. Hence $a=-2$ is the minimum value you’re looking for.

Answer (score 0):

$-a/2$ is a vertex of parabola, for strictly increasing in $(1;2)$ necessary to be  $-a/2 \le 1$ it means $a \ge -2$ and munimum value of $a$ is $-2$.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is monotonically increasing

$\iff$

$f' \ge 0.$

Even strictly mon. increasing implies only $f' \ge 0$ (Example: $y=x^3$, at $x=0$).

1)$f'(x) = 2x +a \ge 0$, $x \in (1,2),$

$0\le 2 +a \lt 2x +a \lt 4 +a$,

$x \in (1,2)$, implies

$\min (a) = -2.$

Check : $f'(x) = 2x -2 \gt 0$, $x \in (1,2),$

hence strictly mon. increasing.